# How to Map Textures Faster

Tags: texturing, uv, vertex-groups

The only way I know of aligning textures is to go into the UV Editing tab, select the surface(s) and manually size up and align that texture by hand, by manipulation of the edges/verts.

What is a quicker way of doing this?  Take this image for instance... just here are nine surfaces which all had to be aligned manually. The edges don't line up exactly, and I'm not even sure how I'd make it line up 'perfectly' across two different surfaces of different models.

[image]

Is there an easier way of doing this? Take Source 2 Hammer for instance, by Valve:

[image]

There are numerical inputs for exactly scaling and sizing, buttons to shift and justify to the centre or to edges, or by view or world-space. I'm unable to find something like this for Blender.

Comment: if you want to quickly put a texture you can create this node chain: Texture Coordinate (Object output) > Mapping node > Image Texture (Box mode instead of Flat) > Diffuse or Principled BSDF > Material Output. Change the Blend value of the Image Texture if necessary. Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'd say it's an improvement. Using an Empty, I'm having to have duplicate entries of the same material for different parts of the map (with different sailing), but it's not as bad as UV mapping every surface. It still just seems odd though, that with everything Blender can do, there isn't just a simple tool or plugin for doing this, such as in Unreal Engine for example.